# How to check svn properties?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is it possible to check the properties are added or not for a particular file while commiting the changes on SVN? Scenario is many time we forgot to add the properties and due to that our process got failed. So is there any way we can automate this i.e. in the absence of these properties  a pop up is generated as a reminder or it don't allow to commit the changes?

Comment: You have hooks (server-side, powered by Subversion) and client-side (powered by TortoiseSVN). But I guess you already knew that—you should probably more specific.

Comment: Yes, you automate this via server-side hooks (pre-commit in this case). Your hook script will probably need to check for properties in the incoming transaction *and* the properties that exist on the versioned items which are being changed as they currently reside in the repository, and reject the commit if appropriate.